# Re-render Data table on click of td of previous page

Tags: angular, typescript, datatables

I am working on angular project with data table(referring this [article](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started)).So my project is like there is one base page and other two pages on it which is shown one at a time by hide/show on click.The first page works fine. But while navigating to the second page the table is showing no data, where as data is available and can be seen in console. And when I insert/update any data the table gets rendered(it gets re-render event).

How do i re-render data table after the click on previous page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using tabs with hide/show, use routes for navigation. In this way you want have problem of re-rendering as data table will load after click which is your requirement.